# getting this error in heroku logs --app <my heroku app name > " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.forest' "

Tags: heroku

**My whole project is here:https://github.com/martinberberi/Cryptocurrency**
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958640+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958640+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958640+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958640+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958641+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958641+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958641+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958641+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958641+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958642+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958642+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958642+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958642+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958643+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958643+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958643+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 790, in exec_module
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958643+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958644+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 8, in 
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958644+00:00 app[web.1]: model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl", "rb"))
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958644+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.forest'
2021-04-22T01:17:26.958794+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 01:17:26 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2021-04-22T01:17:27.098709+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 01:17:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-04-22T01:17:27.098741+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 01:17:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-04-22T01:17:27.155404+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-04-22T01:17:27.217794+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-04-22T01:17:34.872134+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=crypto-currency-api.herokuapp.com request_id=a6e5bd5d-a3f8-4a3b-8476-0de3c868c9ff fwd="24.91.184.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-22T01:25:28.477934+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=crypto-currency-api.herokuapp.com request_id=304ca018-b9eb-4569-8382-95820c101776 fwd="24.91.184.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-22T01:43:00.030720+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-04-22T01:43:09.254965+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2021-04-22T01:43:12.985695+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 01:43:12 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-04-22T01:43:12.987665+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 01:43:12 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:18453 (4)
2021-04-22T01:43:12.987739+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 01:43:12 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-04-22T01:43:12.992120+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 01:43:12 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2021-04-22T01:43:13.061650+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 01:43:13 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2021-04-22T01:43:13.577131+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020315+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 01:43:17 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020322+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020323+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020324+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020324+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020324+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020325+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020325+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020326+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020327+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020327+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020327+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020328+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020328+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020328+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020329+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020329+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020330+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020330+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020331+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020331+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020331+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020332+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 790, in exec_module
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020332+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020332+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 8, in 
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020332+00:00 app[web.1]: model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl", "rb"))
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020333+00:00 app[web.1]: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.forest'**
2021-04-22T01:43:17.020626+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 01:43:17 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2021-04-22T01:43:17.034993+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 01:43:17 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-04-22T01:43:17.034994+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-04-22T01:43:17.034995+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-04-22T01:43:17.034995+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-04-22T01:43:17.034996+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-04-22T01:43:17.034996+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-04-22T01:43:17.034996+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-04-22T01:43:17.034997+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-04-22T01:43:17.034997+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-04-22T01:43:17.034997+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-04-22T01:43:17.034998+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-04-22T01:43:17.034998+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-04-22T01:43:17.034999+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-04-22T01:43:17.034999+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-04-22T01:43:17.034999+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-04-22T01:43:17.034999+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-04-22T01:43:17.035000+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-04-22T01:43:17.035000+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-04-22T01:43:17.035000+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-04-22T01:43:17.035001+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-04-22T01:43:17.035001+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-04-22T01:43:17.035001+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2021-04-22T01:43:17.035002+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 790, in exec_module
2021-04-22T01:43:17.035002+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-04-22T01:43:17.035002+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 8, in 
2021-04-22T01:43:17.035002+00:00 app[web.1]: model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl", "rb"))
2021-04-22T01:43:17.035003+00:00 app[web.1]: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.forest'**
2021-04-22T01:43:17.035268+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 01:43:17 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2021-04-22T01:43:17.235372+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 01:43:17 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 7 was terminated due to signal 15
2021-04-22T01:43:17.325108+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 01:43:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-04-22T01:43:17.325184+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-22 01:43:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-04-22T01:43:17.411261+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-04-22T01:43:17.517724+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-04-22T01:46:48.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user martinberberi@gmail.com
2021-04-22T01:47:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/b703f07c-128a-4f0c-99d4-3220035e7703/activity/builds/c615ff41-0b06-4c90-9e60-e96e9044443c
2021-04-22T01:49:13.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user martinberberi@gmail.com
2021-04-22T01:50:16.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/b703f07c-128a-4f0c-99d4-3220035e7703/activity/builds/a78474d4-687d-4e7c-afef-b4e5956ea04f

Answer (score 0):

the issue was smaller

**see the important file  working directory**

- Procfile
- runtime.txt
- requirements.txt

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

push code again

[more refernce](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python)